# SSIS - Running child packages in Series

Tags: ssis, parallel-processing, package, parent-child

I have a Master package that runs a whole bunch of identical-except-for-the-target-table packages.

Currently they are in an ExecuteChildPackages container, and all run in parallel. Nice.

For sad reasons, it seems like I need them to run in series, NOT in parallel.
I don't care what order they run in, but they need to not overlap.
Obviously I could declare a line of dependencies, but that's not terribly nice.

**Q: Is there any way to tell SSIS that I want this container to do it's ForEachChildPackage loop in series, not in parallel**

Answer (score 1):

I would use a foreach loop that is based on an ADO object that has the package locations stored in it.

Set the foreach parameter to a variable that has package location.

Use an expression on the execute package to define package location.